# jQuery.on("click") firing multiple times for a single click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having trouble with my jQuery code.
Basically I want to load more message entrys after user clicks button.
Problem is, it returns results 3 times.
I have tried literally everything - .unbind (used .bind) / .off / .stopPropagation() and other methods I thought of. I searched all over google, but still couldn`t manage to find solution. Maybe someone can clarify where my problem is?

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#website_post_content_table_bottom_settings_left :input").on("click", function(event){
        if($('.website_post_content_table_data#bigNews').is(":visible")){
            var currentId = $('.website_post_content_table_entry:last').attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/admin_functions.php",
                data: {callFunction: "getMoreNewsEntrys", id: currentId},
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $('.website_post_content_table_data').after(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT:

**HTML**

```
<div id="website_post_content_table_bottom_settings_left">
    <p>Ielādēt papildus:</p>
    <input type="button" style="display:none;">
    <input type="button" id="button_adminLoadMoreEntry" class="adminPanelButton_blue" value="+5">
    <input type="button" id="button_adminLoadMoreEntry" class="adminPanelButton_blue" value="+10">
    <input type="button" id="button_adminLoadMoreEntry" class="adminPanelButton_blue" value="+15">
    <input type="button" id="button_adminLoadMoreEntry" class="adminPanelButton_blue" value="+20">
</div>
```

**EDIT v3:**
I made new javascript file, only for this small code and it STILL returns it 3 times:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#website_post_content_table_bottom_settings_left :input").one("click", function(event){
        $('.website_post_content_table_data').after('<p>Something More</p>');
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you set up demo/jsfiddle

Comment: And what does the HTML look like ?

Comment: @kuwalda can you past your full code, including html

Comment: You can't use the same id multiple times id="button_adminLoadMoreEntry" (but I guess it might not a reason of your issue)

Comment: I added some HTML. Website I am working on is really complicated, so I cant really paste it all here. Maybe if you have idea where is the problem, I can try looking in that direction?
EDIT: id is not causing issue, already tried that!

Comment: @kuwalda its firing only once try here https://jsfiddle.net/iamshajeer/ehxac8o2/

Comment: That is really strange, because $('.website_post_content_table_data').after(html); so could PHP be causing the problem? I added my code in EDIT.

Comment: I see a possible SQL-injection here `$dbconnect,"SELECT * FROM news WHERE id<'".$_POST["id"]."' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5"`

Comment: Is the script shown being loaded more than once?

Comment: @kashesandr Thanks, but at the moment I want to make sure all is working before adding some protection
@charlietfl I am new to jQuery, so I really didn`t understood what you asked?

Comment: @charlietfl's question was not about jQuery, it was about JavaScript. Is there a chance your JavaScript code (i.e. the first code block) is being sent more than once to the browser? (more than one `<script>` tag delivering the same js file.)

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h2hbr6dL/2/ based on @Shajeer Ahmd , doesn't seem to fire more than once. I would guess you have something else hooking it or your document ready code is being set up multiple times.

Comment: @Danguilherme Thanks, but in my case it`s not.

Comment: @kuwalda it is likely something like that, multiple event handlers being bound. Without a way to replicate there isn't much anyone here can do

Comment: Pasting jsfiddle.net/h2hbr6dL/2 in my jQuery file showed that it still outputs it three times, so problem could be outer, but I have no idea what could cause that, because I wrote my code from scratch. Maybe you have any idea where to look?

Comment: Code being loaded again by ajax?

Comment: @charlietfl I am new to jQuery and AJAX. Could you please be more specific what you meant?

Comment: Try debugging the jquery code, put a breakpoint at the $(document).ready(.. line and see how many times that gets loaded, if it is more than once then you need to backtrack and work out what is calling it multiple times

Comment: @kuwalda Is your function calls tree times or ajax successhandler ??

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each()` of [jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop through the element. Then add a reference to each `input` item.
Or try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#website_post_content_table_bottom_settings_left :input").unbind("click").bind("click", function(event){
        if($('.website_post_content_table_data#bigNews').is(":visible")){
            var currentId = $('.website_post_content_table_entry:last').attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "php/admin_functions.php",
                data: {callFunction: "getMoreNewsEntrys", id: currentId},
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $('.website_post_content_table_data').after(html);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What good what that do? Just doing what jQuery already does internally anyway

Comment: I only partly understood what you meant with that. Can you show me example?

Comment: I tried your code, there is "." missing before unbind, but still didn`t work out for me - problem still occurs.

Comment: It still returns three results?

Comment: It does not return anything for me

Comment: add an `error` callback and take a look at the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Jquery.one()`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#website_post_content_table_bottom_settings_left :input").one("click", function(event){
    if($('.website_post_content_table_data#bigNews').is(":visible")){
        var currentId = $('.website_post_content_table_entry:last').attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "php/admin_functions.php",
            data: {callFunction: "getMoreNewsEntrys", id: currentId},
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $('.website_post_content_table_data').after(html);
            }
        });
    }
   });
});
```

This binds the the event only once.
Reference link http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Won't likely help because if you call `one()` several times it will fire for each instance

Comment: How is `one()` going to be called several times in the above code?

Comment: OP's code by itself and run only once can't create the issues OP has. So if it is being called more than once using `one()` won't change anything

Comment: Changed it to .one ,but still text got displayed 3 times. I have no clue what to do..

Answer (score 0):

First of all I must say huge thanks to everyone who tried to help!

My problem was that I had used `display: none;` in my CSS which caused these entries to update in hidden ones.

Still thanks everyone who tried to help! :)